# Can't persist data on localStorage after page refresh using React useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, web-frontend

I'm following a tutorial building a frontend project for recipes and I can't replicate the behavior of persisting the data (that is, if I delete one default recipe and add a new recipe, it should reflect the same after page refresh rather than getting populated by default recipes again). I want to make changes to the page and want it to stay the same after the page refresh.

I'm using React useEffect hook and localStorage for this purpose.

The required code and screenshots are posted below. Please add any of your inputs. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/ft76/NewNew
CSS styles do not reflect here, but feature additions by React like AddRecipe button works fine.

There are other module files for handling recipes etc and I'm going to exclude them because they don't have anything to do with the issue on hand. The code is the following:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import RecipeList from './RecipeList';
import '../css/app.css';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export const RecipeContext = React.createContext()
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'cookingWithReact.recipes';

function App() {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState(sampleRecipes)

  useEffect(() => {
    const recipeJSON = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY);
    if (recipeJSON !== null) {
      setRecipes(JSON.parse(recipeJSON))
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(recipes))
  }, [recipes])

  const recipeContextValue = {
    handleRecipeAdd,
    handleRecipeDelete
  }

  function handleRecipeAdd() {
    const newRecipe = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      name: 'New',
      servings: 1,
      cookTime: '1:00',
      instructions: 'Instructions',
      ingredients: [
        {id: uuidv4(), name: 'Name', amount: '1 Tbs'}
      ]
    }

    setRecipes([...recipes, newRecipe])
  }

  function handleRecipeDelete(id) {
    setRecipes(recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.id !== id))
  }

  return (
    <RecipeContext.Provider value={recipeContextValue}>
      <RecipeList recipes={recipes} />
    </RecipeContext.Provider>
  )
}

const sampleRecipes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Plain Chicken',
    servings: 3,
    cookTime: '1:45',
    instructions: "1. Put salt on chicken.\n2. Put chicken in oven.\n3. Eat the chicken.",
    ingredients : [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Chicken',
        amount: '2 pounds'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Salt',
        amount: '1 Tbs'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Plain Pork',
    servings: 5,
    cookTime: '0:45',
    instructions: "1. Put paprika on pork.\n2. Put pork in oven.\n3. Eat the pork.",
    ingredients : [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Pork',
        amount: '3 pounds'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Paprika',
        amount: '2 Tbs'
      }
    ]
  }
]

export default App;
```

The required screencaps are as follows:

Default screen:
[image]

Screen after deleting one default recipe and adding a new one:
[image]

Screen after refreshing the page:
[image]

Comment: Can you make a codesandbox so that it is easier to fix.

Comment: @Ankit Sure. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/ft76/NewNew) CSS styles do not reflect here, but other React features like AddRecipe button works. Thanks.

Comment: I have answered the question, let me know if you have a query.

Comment: Yes, thanks very much. Please check the replies on the answer. I have asked two queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake in your code is that you were retrieving data from a `const` `array of objects`.

I have changed `sampleRecipes` with a new array `sampleRecipes2` and it will check if the local storage is empty or not, that part is this.

You can initialize `sampleRecipes2` with any `array`.

```
let sampleRecipes2 = [];
  let info = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY);
  if (info === null) {
    sampleRecipes2 = sampleRecipes;
  } else {
    sampleRecipes2 = JSON.parse(info);
  }
```

Overall this should be your `App.js`,

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import RecipeList from "./RecipeList";
import "../css/app.css";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

export const RecipeContext = React.createContext();
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "cookingWithReact.recipes";
function App() {
  let sampleRecipes2 = [];
  let info = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY);
  if (info === null) {
    sampleRecipes2 = sampleRecipes;
  } else {
    sampleRecipes2 = JSON.parse(info);
  }
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState(sampleRecipes2);
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(recipes));
  }, [recipes]);

  const recipeContextValue = {
    handleRecipeAdd,
    handleRecipeDelete
  };

  function handleRecipeAdd() {
    const newRecipe = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      name: "New",
      servings: 1,
      cookTime: "1:00",
      instructions: "Instructions",
      ingredients: [{ id: uuidv4(), name: "Name", amount: "1 Tbs" }]
    };

    setRecipes([...recipes, newRecipe]);
  }

  function handleRecipeDelete(id) {
    setRecipes(recipes.filter((recipe) => recipe.id !== id));
  }

  return (
    <RecipeContext.Provider value={recipeContextValue}>
      <RecipeList recipes={recipes} />
    </RecipeContext.Provider>
  );
}

const sampleRecipes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Plain Chicken",
    servings: 3,
    cookTime: "1:45",
    instructions:
      "1. Put salt on chicken.\n2. Put chicken in oven.\n3. Eat the chicken.",
    ingredients: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Chicken",
        amount: "2 pounds"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Salt",
        amount: "1 Tbs"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Plain Pork",
    servings: 5,
    cookTime: "0:45",
    instructions:
      "1. Put paprika on pork.\n2. Put pork in oven.\n3. Eat the pork.",
    ingredients: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Pork",
        amount: "3 pounds"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Paprika",
        amount: "2 Tbs"
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default App;
```

Comment: Yes, this works as intended, thanks a lot but I have two questions.

1. Since the issue lies in retrieving data from the "const" array, can't we just change it to "let" and make away with the sampleRecipes2? I have made changes in the sandbox and it works the same. Will it lead to any peculiar behavior in edge cases? Please take a look.

2. Can we wrap the whole new block of code in a useEffect hook because the current approach doesn't seem like "React" way of writing code, that is, organised under hooks, functions etc. I'm very new to React so apologies my remarks don't make any sense.

Comment: What if you want to use the array in any other file in future then you have to create a new one and there might not be only 2 objects, that why I didn't change it to const, but you can change it to let anyways. Ok I will have a look at the second one.